# String.matches() is not matching

Tags: java

condition is not matching.

```
string1 = "k"
string2 = "k(1)"
String regex = "\\\d+";
if ((string1 +"("+regex+")").matches(string2)) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://java67.blogspot.in/2012/09/java-string-matches-example-regular-expression.html

Answer (score 1):

Other way round. It's `s.matches(regexp)`, not `regexp.matches(s)`!

You should also escape the round brackets ('(' and ')') as they have a special meaning in regular expressions. So it should be:

```
string2.matches(Pattern.quote(string1) + "\\(" + regex + "\\)");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are interverting the argument. The regex must be passed in parameter of the `matches` method and the method must be called on the String to be parsed :

```
string2.matches(string1 + "(" + regex + ")")
```